# What does <| in this code mean?

Tags: javascript, syntax, operators

```
function foo() {}
var bar = foo <| function() {};
```

This is the first time I've seen something like this. What does `<|` mean?

Source: https://github.com/allenwb/ESnext-experiments/blob/master/ST80collections-exp1.js

Comment: It's not valid javascript syntax and will cause an error. Is it suposed to be `var bar = foo || function() {};`?

Comment: That is either invalid syntax or an obscure language extension.

Comment: Well, I've seen `|>` used for function composition/pipelining, this might be the reverse version... but neither JavaScript nor any other language with `function` keyword I know has operators for that.

Comment: I saw this in a GitHub example. I thought it was pure JavaScript.

Comment: @David - Please provide a link so we can get some context.

Comment: How is that out of 9 identical answers, most of them got an upvote but not mine? =P

Comment: @Ben Lee - We knew that you would complain so we preemptively gave down-votes for a net of 0.

Comment: https://github.com/allenwb/ESnext-experiments/blob/master/ST80collections-exp1.js

Comment: Source: https://github.com/allenwb/ESnext-experiments/blob/master/ST80collections-exp1.js

Comment: @David - I knew it was a language extension! Who would make such a weird mistake.

Comment: @David - This is possible syntax for a future version of JavaScript.

Comment: @David let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2902/discussion-between-chaospandion-and-david)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Now that you have posted the link to the source, you can see in the comments at the top of the file exactly what it does ([line 36](https://github.com/allenwb/ESnext-experiments/blob/master/ST80collections-exp1.js#L36)):

> the <| operator -- defines the [[Prototype]] of a literal...
>
> For these examples <| used with a function expression sets the
>   [[Prototype]] of the object created as the value of the function's
>   "prototype" property to the value of the "prototype" property of the
>   the LHS object.  This is in addition to setting the [[Prototype]] of
>   the function object itself. In other words, it builds sets the
>   [[Prototype]] of both the function and of function.prototype to
>   potentially different values.

**Update:** I've just remembered this question as I came across the [full ECMAScript Harmony proposal for this "literal [[Prototype]] operator"](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aproto_operator). There is a lot more information in there than in the quote above, so it's worth a read.

Comment: Sorry I was just scanning through and I didn't catch that. Thanks

Comment: And for clarity and completeness, this is for es.next which is for (after some googling) [ECMAScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) (Whatever that is)

Comment: @Joseph - ECMAScript is the standard upon which implementations such as JavaScript or JScript are built.

Comment: Fascinating... so why doesn't js recognize this constructor if it's built off of ECMA?

Comment: @Joseph - I'm surprised that someone experienced in JavaScript was unaware of ECMAScript.

Comment: @ChaosPandion indeed.  Every thing I know is from fiddling with js for fun.  I started out with `onmousover="this.style.color = red"` (which thrilled me to no end) and slowly grew in my knowledge base.  Unfortunately that method of learning often precludes much of the learning of the history of the language.  I'll be the first to say that my knowledge of js is "upsidedown". (btw, know of any good sources to learn the history of javascript?)

Comment: The second and third links here: http://javascript.crockford.com/ have some history in them. The whole thing is a good read though.

Comment: Thank you so much @dtanders! this will be immensely helpful!

Comment: It's nice to see that someone actually did some research for this question. I'm appalled by the number of **wrong** answers... To make matters worse, they have upvotes.

Comment: @Rick - To be fair, the OP didn't edit the question to include the link until a few answers had already been posted. Although perhaps they could have checked to see if a link was posted a bit later, as there were several people asking for one.

Comment: @James - to be fair... you're still the only one that bothered to actually try researching the operator instead of making short sighted guesses (and in some cases, making things up). Anyway, still a great answer :)

Answer (score 7):

It looks like it should be

```
function foo() {}
var bar = foo || function() {};
```

Which will assign foo to bar, if foo is defined and assign an empty function to bar otherwise.

About the link you posted later, it is still not valid Javascript.  The project's README explains the purpose of the file.

> This project contains example files of the various language extensions
>   that are being considered for inclusion in the next editions of the
>   ECMA Language Specification. The purpose of examples is to test the
>   utility, writability, and readability of proposed features. There is
>   no guarentee that any of these will actually be incorporated into the
>   language.

A description of the proposed functionality brackets the lines of code you pasted into your question.

```
the <| operator -- defines the [[Prototype]] of a literal

/* Quote that James posted */

function foo() {};
const bar = foo <| function() {};

Object.getPrototypeOf(bar)===foo; //true
Object.getPrototypeOf(bar.prototype)===foo.prototype;  //true
```

Answer (score 0):

That throws a syntax error for me ("unexpected token" on the "|")

**[For A complete list of javascript operators go here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators)**

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin ... I know there is... header is bigger.

Comment: As a community that supports web development. That serves as a bad example. Also, there's no actual need for it to be bigger. :-)

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin Point taken.  It comes from when I place my demo link in the header on most if not all of the answers I provide a demo on. (not sure exactly what's wrong with using an h tag though... does it majorly affect screen readers or something?)

Comment: It does. Also it affects Google search.

Comment: You should do research before posting answers that are incorrect. `<|` is proposal operator for assigning prototypes in ES.next.

Comment: @Rick dude... this was like a week ago, and everything in my answer was correct.  There was nothing wrong with my answer.  There is no *current* `<|` operator in *javascript* (which the poster tagged this question as) at *this point in time*.  All I did was say that it "throws a syntax error" and gave a link to the docs listing all current javascript operators.  You really should ***read the whole question*** and ***the whole answer*** (i.e. "do research") before downvoting. :P

Comment: So, I've re-read the question and there is definitely nothing I missed... "This is the first time I've seen something like this. What does <| mean?" You did not answer this question, you simply told them it would throw a syntax exception, -1.

On the other hand, James Allardice _did_ spend time researching the correct answer, +1.

As for trying to spin it with "There is no current <| operator in javascript" - this is also b.s. as the link he gave is to Allen Wirfs-Brock's Narcissus fork with `<|`, which means you _can_ write code with that operator and run it successfully using that build.

Comment: @Rick here we go again.  You did miss something.  You missed something very important.  Fact: The original context of the question was javascript with no mention of ecmascript. Fact: The poster did not even post the link to the script until after I posted my answer. Fact: James Allardice only posted after the link to the actual script was posted. Fact: No one else provided a list of current operators for js.  Fact: I thought to leave this post for those looking for js operators in the *future* (I thought my post was constructive enough not to delete).  Fact: you did not do the *full* research.

Comment: Fact: If I had written an answer that turned out to be patently incorrect, I would, at very least, update it with corrections (while leaving my original intact).

Comment: Also, I down-voted everyone that gave bogus answers to this question, so it's definitely not personal - you should try to keep that in mind while writing your next response.

Comment: @Rick The thing is it isn't incorrect.  I stated a solid fact that it "throws a syntax error for me".  I also provided a useful link, and had I not included the link I would have removed my answer (like I have in the past).  The thing I don't get is why you decided to go on a downvote run in a thread you didn't even contribute to.  Yes I do think it's personal based on your statement "I'm *appalled* by the number of wrong answers" (emphasis added).  I think you do have a personal issue with the majority of the answers given regardless of if they are helpful to someone in the future or not.